# Continuity in $\mathbb R^n$.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

we just got started with this topic today, and I am confused.
Let $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R $
with
$$f(x,y) =\begin{cases}   
y\sin(x)/x &\text{if } x \ne 0\\  
0 &\text{else}
\end{cases}$$

Now, for $x \not= 0$ it is continuous, because its components are.
But what do I have to do to show (dis)continuity?
I know I have to approach a point (I guess $(0,y)$) with every curve possible.
What I have tried so far, but believe to be false:
I approximate $y\cdot\sin(x)/x$ as follows:
Let $x$ be $\not= 0$.
$|f(x,y)| = |y|\cdot|\sin(x)|/|x| \le   |y|\cdot|x|/|x| = |y|  \to |y| \text{ for } (x,y) \to (0,y)$
I don't quite know what I can tell from this, because of the less than or equal sign.

If somebody could help me I'd appreciate it a lot! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the limit at $(0,b)$ with $b\neq 0$ yields $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,b)} \left(y\dfrac {\sin (x)}x\right)= \lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,b)}(y)=b$, which implies $\lim \limits_{(0,b)} (f)=b\neq 0=f(0,b)$.

Therefore $f$ isn't continuous.

Comment: Ok, I get that, but why do I take the limit at (0,0)? Why not (0,42) or anything else? Because then the limit would be 42, which is clearly not equal to 0, therefore f isn't continuous.

Comment: @RunOrVeith Misread question. Sorry. I'll fix this.

Comment: @RunOrVeith I fixed it, but you had gotten it anyway. If you post an answer to this question doing what you did in your comment, I'll delete my answer. I'd even prefer to do so.

Comment: No, I'll leave yours. I just got lucky, more or less, as I was able to get this question, but I'm stuck on the other ones as well. Thanks!